# Ipyleaflet will not add layer with the use of geopandas

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipyleaflet

I am trying to load in a shapefile with the use of geopandas. I have read the file in, but when I go to add the layer to the ipyleaflet map, an error comes up that says 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'model_id'.
I have tried many files and it just will not read with the geodataframe.

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps
fire_was = gpd.read_file('fire_wa.shp')
#add map

center = [47.409824923593575,-120.43401014843751]zoom = 7
m = Map(basemap=basemaps.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik, center=center, zoom=zoom)
```

`m.add_layer(fire_was)`

`m`

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The example I had seen did not show the below but checked more of the documentation of ipyleaflet. You must use GeoData to load the geodataframe.

```
from ipyleaflet  import Map, GeoData, basemaps, LayersControl
```

`fire_was = gpd.read_file('fire_wa.shp') firewa = GeoData(geo_dataframe = fire_was)`

```
m = Map(center =(47.409824923593575,-120.43401014843751), zoom =7,basemap= basemaps.Esri.WorldTopoMap)
```

`m.add_layer(firewa)`

`m`